# Simple JavaScript search box

Tags: javascript, html

I tried connecting the first text box, so it would turn it into a URL, and then when 'search' is clicked, it would jump to that website, not sure if it's impossible, or i'm just clueless, but would really appreciate some help, thank you in advance!

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function link() {
      var link_s = document.getElementById('link_id').value;
      document.getElementById('link_str').innerHTML = link_s.link()
    }
  </script>

  <h2> Search box </h2>
  <input type='text' id='link_id'>
  <input type='button' id='link_str' value='Search' onClick='link()'>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Using the same identifier for function name and variable name may not be a very good idea.

Comment: You should do a little more research/homework.

Comment: Well, what is `str` and where is it defined? You've either left that out of your snippet or are trying to use an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this JavaScript:

```
function goTo()
{
    location.href = document.getElementById('link_id').value;
}
```

and change the `onclick` in the HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='link_id'>
<input type='button' id='link' value='Search' onClick='javascript:goTo()'>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to follow the unobtrusive JavaScript way, you would move the `onclick` completely into your JavaScript code, and remove it in the HTML:

```
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function()
{
    location.href = document.getElementById('link_id').value;
};
```

Comment: This is really good, i'l take a further look into it, thank you!

Comment: The "onclick" event does not require "javascript:" inside. Also remember to add "return false" to avoid a form being submitted. `<input type="button" id="link" value="Search" onclick="goTo(); return false;">` or, even better, in the FORM HTML tag, add the "onsubmit" event with return false `<form action="..." method="..." onsubmit="return false;">`.

Comment: @AlejandroIván A lot of times if you are trying to access other JavaScript variables you want your function to execute in the global context. Also, his button is not `type="submit"` and isn't inside of `form` tags so it will not submit anything.

Comment: Is there a way where I don't have to write 'http://', and just the domain name by itself?

Comment: change it to be `location.href = 'http://' + document.getElementById('link_id').value;`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
 <input type="text" id="link-box"/>
 <input type="button" id="search-button" value="Search" 
        onclick="window.location = document.getElementById('link-box').value;"/>
```

Of course you could do this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function func(){
           window.location = document.getElementById('link-box').value;
      }
 </script>
```

With `onclick="func();"`

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById("search-button").onclick = function(){
            window.location = document.getElementById('link-box').value;  
       };        
 </script>
```

Or last of all

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById("search-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
            window.location = document.getElementById('link-box').value;
       });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you! And thanks to all the comments, I know what I did wrong now!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to create a form that will search google use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dos12(g1) {
window.open('https://www.google.com/#q='+g1 +" site:linkedin.com",      'G1window');
}

      </script>
  <form onsubmit="dos12(this.g1.value); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="g1" size="20" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    Search Linkedin via Google<br />
    <br />
  </form>
```

If you want to search a website then you will need to get the search string used. for example, if you want to search the ABN lookup site for Australia you would use the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dos10(a1) {
window.open('http://abr.business.gov.au/SearchByName.aspx?SearchText=' + a1,   'a1window');
}

      </script>
  <form onsubmit="dos10(this.a1.value); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="a1" size="20" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    ABN Lookup name<br />
    <br />
  </form>
```

hope this helps. you don't need to add anything else. Just copy and paste this into notepad or your code editor and save as test.html then open with browser to test it.