# PHP url routing and pretty urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes

I have this url that is generated from a form that is supposed to search inside a database for an event: `http://localhost:8080/search?event=ecddf4`
I want that the url is rewrited in this way: `http://localhost:8080/search/event/ecddf4`
I'm using FastRoute as my php routing system but I want to try something more documented like [`Simple Router`](https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router) . I have this rules inside my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

I use this set of rules for both routing systems but I'm unable to obtain a pretty url when the form is submitted. Can anyone explain me how to achieve this?It's few time that I'm using FastRoute and I will start tomorrow with php-simple-router. Someone suggested me to map an url with regexp but how?I've readed the documentations but it's not clear form me if i need to set a placeholder like this `/search/{event}` to rewrite the url?

this is the form I have to submit the search:

```
<form method="GET" action="search" name="">
 <input type="search" name="event" />
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "I'm unable to obtain a pretty url when the form is submitted" - can you describe what this means? It's unclear to me if it's about generating the `action` of the form based on the routes defined with `FastRoute` or something else.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv As you can see in the question, I'm mapping the form submit action to `search` that is a route I've mapped inside `FastRoute` and will point to a controller. I want obtain a pretty url instead of an url with a classic query string when form is submitted  example `localhost\search\event\xxx` insted of `localhost\search?event=xxx`

Comment: So then you either use JavaScript to build the URL _or_ use a htaccess rewrite. Got it.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I would like a non JS solution if is possible. I've totally migrated my projects to `Simple Router` that is more complete than `FastRoute`, so every solution that will work well with it will be appreciated.

Comment: What you're asking for has nothing to do with the PHP routing solution. It's all about redirecting (NOT rewriting) `?foo=bar` to `foo/bar` through Apache HTTPD's config. It's a bad solution IMHO (redirecting on every request, meaning two server roundtrips instead of one) instead of building the proper URLs in the client.

Comment: Ok, what if I submit the form on itself and then redirect trought php? 
can you provide an example of a good practice to rebuild the url using your suggested JS way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167236/simple-javascript-search-box maybe